# Сортировка Map<Integer, String[]>

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, map

Имеется следующий код.

```java
Map<Integer, String[]> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

hashMap.put(1, new String[] {"числа1" , "7", "8", "3"});
hashMap.put(2, new String[] {"числа2" , "4", "1", "4"});
hashMap.put(3, new String[] {"числа3" , "2", "4", "1"});
hashMap.put(4, new String[] {"числа4" , "1", "6", "5"});
hashMap.put(5, new String[] {"числа5" , "1", "6", "2"});
```

Как его отсортировать мапу по убыванию, по **последнему** значению в массиве String[], и вывести в консоль?
Вывод в консоль в этом примере должен получится такой

```
числа4 , 1, 6, 5
числа2 , 4, 1, 4
числа1 , 7, 8, 3
числа5 , 1, 6, 2
числа3 , 2, 4, 1
```

Т.е. сортировка производилась именно по последнему элементу внутри массива string[].

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```java
Map<Integer, String[]> collect = hashMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
            final String s1 = e1.getValue()[e1.getValue().length - 1];
            final String s2 = e2.getValue()[e2.getValue().length - 1];
            return s2.compareTo(s1);
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (o1, o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Но проблема в том, что у вас числа записаны как переменные типа String, поэтому сортировка будет производится именно для этих переменных и она не соответсвует сортировке для чисел. Если необходимо сортировать по последнему значению массива, воспринимая это значение именно как число, а не как строчную переменную, то сделайте так:

```java
Map<Integer, String[]> collect1 = hashMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
            final Integer s1 = Integer.valueOf(e1.getValue()[e1.getValue().length - 1]);
            final Integer s2 = Integer.valueOf(e2.getValue()[e2.getValue().length - 1]);
            return s2.compareTo(s1);
        })
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (o1, o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, второй вариант работает так, как надо

Comment: @Александр главное, чтобы в массиве последний элемент не был null и всегда являлся числом. иначе получите исключение

Comment: А может еще подскажете как вывести из этой сортированной мапы только первые десять ? У меня в ней около 1000 значений, а по заданию требуется вывести на экран топ 10

Comment: @Александр это достаточно просто, добавьте вызов limit(10) в стриме, указав нужное количество элементов, в этом случае в свою коллекцию вы получите столько элементов, сколько хотите. ответ откорректировал

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь мой web crawler работает как надо )

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить коллекцию *значений* мапы, отсортировать её по четвертой колонке в обратном порядке и собрать в лист `List<String[]>`:

```java
Map<Integer, String[]> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, new String[]{"числа1", "7", "8", "3"});
hashMap.put(2, new String[]{"числа2", "4", "1", "4"});
hashMap.put(3, new String[]{"числа3", "2", "4", "1"});
hashMap.put(4, new String[]{"числа4", "1", "6", "5"});
hashMap.put(5, new String[]{"числа5", "1", "6", "2"});

List<String[]> values = hashMap.values().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(val -> val[3], Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

values.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [числа4, 1, 6, 5]
// [числа2, 4, 1, 4]
// [числа1, 7, 8, 3]
// [числа5, 1, 6, 2]
// [числа3, 2, 4, 1]
```

---

См. [`Как сортировать ArrayList<DataModel>?`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214461/419583)